# DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of Python 2.6 exception.__class__, exception.message,

Tags: python, exception, python-2.6, deprecation-warning

Can anyone tell me the actual reason behind the warning I am getting in this Django middleware, and how can I solve this?

I am getting this message "*DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of Python 2.6  exception.**class**, exception.message,*"

```
class GeneralMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if exception.__class__ is SandboxError:
            # someone is trying to access a sandbox that he has no
            # permission to
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/notpermitted/")

        exc_type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
        data = traceback.format_tb(
                    tb, None) + traceback.format_exception_only(
                    exc_type, value)
        msg = (
            "Failure when calling method:\n"
            u"URL:'%s'\nMethod:'%s'\nException Type:'%s'\n"
            u"Error Message '%s'\nFull Message:\n%s"
            % (request.get_full_path(), request.method,
               exception.__class__, exception.message,
```

Comment: Try `isinstance(exception, SandboxError)` instead of `exception.__class__ is SandboxError`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me blender... thanks for your fast response. Actually I'm getting the warning on exception.__class__, exception.message this line.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I remember correctly, when Python switched to the new raise syntax in 2.5(?), they got rid of the `message` member in favor of an `args` tuple. For backward compatibility, `BaseException.message` is effectively the same thing as `BaseException.args[0] if BaseException.args else None`, but you shouldn't use it in new code.

So, change `message` to either `args` (if you want all args) or `args[0]` (or, if you're worried there may be no args, the fancier version that protects against `()`), depending on which you want.

The reason for this change is that with the new-style exceptions, there's no magic to `raise` or `except` anymore; you're just calling the exception class's constructor in the `raise` statement, and catching the exception in a variable in the `except` statement. So:

```
try:
  raise MyException('Out of cheese error', 42)
except Exception as x:
  print x.args
```

This will print `('Out of cheese error', 42)`. If you only had `print x.message` you'd just get `'Out of cheese error'`. So, the Exception subclasses that used to have to do fancy things to carry around an error code as a separate member, etc., can be simplified; in fact, the whole thing comes down to this:

```
class BaseException(object):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args = args
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `SandboxError` class inherited from the `Exception` class? If not, you will get this message. The reasoning is described in [PEP352](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/).

In code, your exception should be defined like this:

```
class SandboxException(Exception):
    ....
```

Comment: Yes i have inherit SandboxError class from Exception.                class SandboxError(Exception):
    pass